# Add rows in excel table with API Graph

Tags: excel, graph, rows, addition

I am trying to add 2 rows in an excel table whose file is located in a sharepoint site.

To get the details of the file - and double check that I have the correct id's - I do the following :

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/list/items/{item-id} -> all ok, I see the details of the excel file (createdBy, ModifiedBy, etc..)`

But when doing :

`POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/list/items/{item-id}/workbook/tables/{table-name}/rows/add`

I get the following error message : **Resource not found for the segment 'workbook'** I don't understand

Has someone any idea what I am doing wrong and could this error message mean ?

The documentation I base on this is here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/tablerowcollection-add

Thank you
Andreas

Comment: Strangely, when I test this on the graph explorer I have no error. The job in not done (insert values in my table), but the output shoot me no error and a 200 OK instead

Answer (score 1):

Well, the correct url is actually the following :

POST [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/list/items/{item-id}/driveitem/workbook/tables/{table-name}/rows/add](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/%7Bdrive-id%7D/list/items/%7Bitem-id%7D/driveitem/workbook/tables/%7Btable-name%7D/rows/add)

note the **driveitem** added in the url !

The way I got there is the following :

to get the drive ID do:
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{hostname}.sharepoint.com:/sites/{SiteName}:/drives](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7Bhostname%7D.sharepoint.com:/sites/%7BSiteName%7D:/drives)

Then the list of the items
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0s/drives/{drive-id}/list/items](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0s/drives/%7Bdrive-id%7D/list/items)

and the id of the item you are looking for
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/list/items/{item-id}](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/%7Bdrive-id%7D/list/items/%7Bitem-id%7D)

Answer (score 0):

Depending how you call the graph url, I think you should avoid the %20 in the url but instead use a "+" or try with a simple space " ".

Hope this helps